# R jsonlite fromJSON very slow on large files--is this expected?

Tags: r, json, performance, etl, jsonlite

I am trying to figure out if the time elapsed using `fromJSON` that I'm looking at is typical or a red flag, because it's multiple orders of magnitude slower than I have grown to expect from R in any situation.

I'm using files from [these API endpoints](https://scryfall.com/docs/api/bulk-data) (i.e., I get JSON in, I do not have control over the form of the JSON before it is imported, it is theoretically the same every time), namely the `default cards` and `all cards` bulk files. I use `download.file()` to retrieve them and then load the saved files with `fromJSON`.

The ~281mb `default cards` file takes between 65 and 95 seconds to `fromJSON` in. The ~1.5gb `all cards` file, which is similarly-structured because they're both sets of Card objects, takes between 25 and 45 *minutes*. (I am using R 4.2.1 in RStudio on Windows 11 with a SSD and 64gb of RAM, if that matters; peak memory usage tops out around ~12gb RAM.)

Is that in the realm of reasonable expectation for files of this size/complexity, including the nonlinear increase in processing time, or should I be treating it as a red flag? I have no basis of comparison for JSON as opposed to CSV and don't mean to be disrespectful if the answer is in fact that this is as fast as it gets, I just didn't want to assume that was normal.

To reproduce/see on your own machine:

1. Get `https://api.scryfall.com/bulk-data` directly from that url to get the download links for "default" and "all cards" data
2. download.file() the JSON for "default" and "all" cards
3. Try `fromJSON()` on the resulting files (I am using default settings and only entering that filepath)
4. *(Optional)* The numbers I'm citing are from benchmarking with tictoc.

(Same query with different framing posted on the jsonlite issue tracker [here](https://github.com/jeroen/jsonlite/issues/401).)

I am open to suggestions for either making this go faster or alternative download/import methods that would be less of a drag. This is in the concept of a scripted ETL process that ultimately should be able to run as a cron job without human interaction.

Comment: try RcppSimdJson?

Comment: @MichaelChirico ! Wow! I'll have to explore a bit to make sure that it's also handling the nested arrays okay, but the speed's fantastic. Thank you so much!

Comment: For the simple use-case of processing JSON text that's already in R, I found that directly calling `jsonlite:::parse_string(txt, bigint_as_char=F)`, and thus bypassing the error-checking and other processing in `jsonlite::fromJSON`, gave me a ~6x speedup.